# PowerShell Add PS-Drive to robocopy to a device outside of the domain

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm currently creating a PowerShell script that basically maps the network drive from a NAS  which is outside of the domain, but I get the following error message:

```
New-PSDrive : The network path was not found
...
+ New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $credential  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (X:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

This is the following code:

```
$nasipaddress = "192.168.0.110"
$nasusername = ".\nas-local"
$naspassword = cat "F:\Skript\password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($nasusername, $naspassword)

robocopy F:\Admin$ \\$nasipaddress\robocopy /MIR /PURGE /e /log+:$filepath
```

Robocopy works just fine, but it needs authentication credentials and that's the reason why it doesn't run when the PC is inactive for a while, that's why I'm implementing it to map it first. It has to be mapped temporarily, not persistent.

I think it might be because it's not a domain device, but I might be wrong here. Did google a lot, like really a lot, but couldn't find anything that worked so here's my last resort. Not that experienced with PowerShell, but on my way to mastering it.

Best Regards and thank you very much

*stillrigeway*

Answer (score 0):

You should map to a share, are you exposing a share from the NAS?

Can you provide the full "New-PSDrive" with your arguments?

Also, if this in a script, set the Scope parameter value to "Global" to ensure the drive persists outside the current scope.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2